# Removing section in .sub file and renumber rest of lines?

Tags: video-editing, subtitles

Here's the problem: An AVI file had a few seconds removed when it was ripped from a DVD, while its corresponding .sub subtitle file still contains the whole thing.

So at around 2/3 into the movie, I need to remove the extra subtitles, and renumber the rest of the lines in the .sub files so that the remaining subtitles are displayed at the right time.

I was hoping that [SubTitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw) would be able to renumber the rest of the lines after I deleted the now-useless section, but it doesn't.

What would be the easiest way to edit the sub file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is my experience in doing that.
open the .sub in excel as .txt and do re-numbing after eliminating the column that contains the old numbers.
export the file into .txt, you will notice a [tab] space between the time code and the subtitle of it.
it's simple after that to get rid of the that space. in notepad find and replace the [tab] space with nothing.

save the file as .sub